# jquery ajax printa index na tela

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tendo problemas com o jquery pois ele inves de printar na tela só o echo do meu php ele esta printando toda a index na tela como resolver isso ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      function enviar(){
        var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
        var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
        var index = 0;
        linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

          setTimeout(

            function(){
              $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: "bin=" + value,
                success: function(resultado){
                  document.write(resultado + "<br>");
              }
            })

          }, 10 * index);

        index = index + 3;

        })
      }
  </script>



<?php





error_reporting(0);

 if ($_POST['ip']) {
$bin = substr($_POST['ip'], 0, 90);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "fonte dps testes");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "fonte dos testes" );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $s = curl_exec($ch);
        $pop = preg_match( '/<p>(.*)<\/p>/si' , $s , $match);


$vdd = ' ';

if($pop >= "1") 

{ $vdd = "<b><font color='red'>#DIE_IPS </font></b>"; } 

else { $vdd = "<b><font color='green'>#LIVE_IPS </font></b>"; }


 $tudo = " [".$ip." ".$vdd."] ";


 echo "<br><br><center>".$vdd." ".$ip."</center>";
   }else{}
?>
```

Comment: Pode mostrar como está seu código PHP ?

Comment: Por favor, mostre tambem o seu PHP,

Comment: Editei a pergunta ali esta o php

Comment: @BrunoLazarine O PHP está junto com o HTML? ou no arquivo, só tem esse codigo PHP?

Comment: Esta junto e desejo printar so o resultado do php

Comment: Para printar apenas o echo do PHP, este deve estar em um arquivo sem a presença de HTML

Comment: Mais eu desejo que seja printando na index  a baixo de textarea sem redirecionamento como faço ?

Comment: Use JQuery com um seletor. Por exemplo se abaixo do textarea tem uma div cujo id é response, faça : $("#response").html(resultado);

Essa código vai dentro do success na chamada $.ajax

Comment: Obrigado por me dar uma luz, porem como eu inplementaria essa mudança em meu codigo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separe os arquivos, crie um arquivo só para o PHP. 
Ex:

IP.php

```
<?php

$bin = substr($_POST['ip'], 0, 90);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "fonte dps testes");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "era um garoto=que como eu" );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $s = curl_exec($ch);
        $pop = preg_match( '/<p>(.*)<\/p>/si' , $s , $match);


$vdd = ' ';

if($pop >= "1") 

{ $vdd = "<b><font color='red'>#DIE_IPS </font></b>"; } 

else { $vdd = "<b><font color='green'>#LIVE_IPS </font></b>"; }


 $tudo = " [".$ip." ".$vdd."] ";


 echo "<br><br><center>".$vdd." ".$ip."</center>";
   }else{}
?>
```

OutroArquivo.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      function enviar(){
        var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
        var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
        var index = 0;
        linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

        setTimeout(
            function(){
                $.ajax({
                url: 'IP.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: "bin=" + value,
                success: function(resultado){
                    document.write(resultado + "<br>");
                }
            })

      }, 10 * index);

    index = index + 3;

    })
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mais como eu faria para printar diretamente na index sem qualquer tipo de redirecionamento ?

Comment: @BrunoLazarine Da forma que falei, ele não atualiza a pagina, a intenção é retornar na mesma pagina, por isso usamos Ajax